# Find value from a search list in a cell ( Excel Formula; Sumif, sumproduct etc )

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, formula

I have a question as below:

I have a list of numbers in a different sheet ( INFO) in a column for example H:H:

```
Includes?
59701
59702
59744
59761
59774
59817
```

... and I have a details in different sheet (DB) at U:U:

```
3*58.00  Std - 7*17.40 N59020:
2*72.00 : Std - 7*21.60 N59020:
7*72.00 : Std - 7*21.60 N59020:
5*100.00 N59872:
71*100.00 N59872:
```

I write a formula in DB column "Z2":

```
=IF(SUMIF(U2;"*59701*")>0;"Yes";
    IF(SUMIF(U2;"*59702*")>0;"Yes";
       IF(SUMIF(U2;"*59744*")>0;"Yes";"No") ...
```

My question is top formula need to define all search details, I need to repeat every number that includes at search Info.

Is there a way to define this Info search list, in order not to repeat the formula for every different number?

Thank you for your supports and sorry for my English.

Comment: are they always 5 digits and always at the end like you examples?

Comment: BTW I think you translated the formula incorrectly.  You probably meant COUNTIF not SUMIF because SUMIF will try to sum it and if it is a string like you show it will always return `0` even if found.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes sorry countif, and for now  always 5 digits...

Comment: Then try: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID(U2;LEN(U2)-5;5);'Info'!H:H;0));"Yes";"No")`

Comment: @ScottCraner, i tried it but in U2 this number maybe starting at 13, sometimes 9, for example (3*58.00  Std - 7*17.40 N59020:) it starts 24, but searching number always 5digits.

Comment: That is why I asked if it is always at the end like your examples.  All your examples have it starting 6 places from the right.  If it always start 6 places from the right then this will work.  It does not matter the full length of the string just that the numbers are 6 places from the right.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry for that, i tought you are asking about source search criteria, in U2 where searching number details always changing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,just sharing;

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(U2;Info!$I$2:$I$28));"Yes";"")
```

In column I:I i made formula to add wildcharacter "*"; for example now search become --

> *59701*

thank you for all for helping :)